# I want to update my user list on submitting the club form which automatically creates a club admin which in turn is a user in activeadmin

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, activeadmin

My dashboard.rb is:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Dashboard" do

  menu priority: 1, label: proc{ I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard") }

  content title: proc{ I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard") } do
    # form render 'form'
    # Here is an example of a simple dashboard with columns and panels.

    columns do
      column class: "users" do
        table_for User.all.order(:created_at), input_html: { class: "table table-bordered" } do
          column "User Id", :id
          column "Email", :email
          column "User Role" do |role|
            role.profile.role
          end
        end
      end

      column do
        render partial: 'form', locals: { club: Club.new }
      end

    end
  end
end
```

My form partial is in app/views/admin/dashboard/_form.html.erb and it is:

```
<%= semantic_form_for :club, url: admin_clubs_url, method: :post, builder: ActiveAdmin::FormBuilder, remote: true do |club| %>
<%= club.inputs "Details" do %>
    <%= club.input :name, label: 'Club Name' %>
    <%= club.input :email, label: 'Club Admin Email', input_html: { value: '' } %>
    <%= club.inputs for: [:club_profile_attributes] do |ff| %>
        <%= ff.input :country_id, as: :select, collection: Country.get_id_and_name, include_blank: false %>
        <%= ff.input :logo, as: :file %>
        <%= ff.input :email, label: 'Club Email' %>
        <%= ff.input :phone_number_1, label: 'Phone Number' %>
    <% end %>
    <%= club.actions %>
<% end %>
```

Now how do I use an ajax request to update my users in dashboard.rb file, so whenever I create a club my user list gets updated using the ajax request/response.

Answer (score 0):

`$('#form_id').on('ajax:success', function(event, data, status, xhr){});`

`ajax:success` and other [custom events](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax) can be used to handle responses from `remote: true` forms.  You would need to send the updated user list with the response data and then append or replace the user list.